# Adding map library to android studio

Tags: android, maps, neshan, neshan-android-sdk

I want to add new library to my android project i add this :

```
repositories {       
    maven { url "https://dl.bintray.com/neshan/neshan-android-sdk" }
}
```

and this :

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'neshan-android-sdk:mobile-sdk:0.9.1'
}
```

but there is an error after sync gradle:

```
Error:(32, 13) Failed to resolve: neshan-android-sdk:mobile-sdk:0.9.1
```

(my targetSdkVersion is 25)

is there any one know how can i fix it??

Comment: where did you add maven repository to? which file?

Comment: @Mostafa have you followed all steps given in the link .Have you register to https://developers.neshan.org/

Comment: i add maven repository to build.gradel project level

Comment: yes i registered in the site

Answer (score 3):

Your library version is old and deleted from repository,
 you should use newer version of library
see [Neshan Map Document](https://developers.neshan.org/android-sdk/guides/getting-started/)

Current version of `NeshanMobileSDK` is **0.9.5**

Answer (score 0):

Check with the dependency, it should contain

`group_name:artifactory_name:version_name`

Answer (score 0):

**Project Level `build.gradle`**

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
        maven { url "https://dl.bintray.com/neshan/neshan-android-sdk" }
    }
}
```

**App `build.gradle`**

```
dependencies {
    //Neshan sdk library
    implementation 'neshan-android-sdk:mobile-sdk:0.9.5'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Bare in mind that in `build.gradle (Project: ***)`, there is two regions for `repositories`. One is under `buildscript` and the other is under `allprojects`, you should put the maven repository in `allprojects` region. And your `build.gradle (Project: ***)` should look like below:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        // Putting maven URL here, will be useless! Please scroll down 
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.1'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        // Right place for repository URL
        maven {
            url  "https://dl.bintray.com/neshan/neshan-android-sdk"
        }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

And to make sure that everything else is in place, compare your `build.gradle (module:app)` with mine:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.myapp.my"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    splits {
        abi {
            enable true
            reset()
            include 'armeabi-v7a'
            universalApk false
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0-beta01'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:2.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:2.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.2.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:17.0.0'
    //Neshan sdk library
    implementation 'neshan-android-sdk:mobile-sdk:0.9.5'
}
```